# jquery hide/show is not working as expected in node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am new to node js, I am building one application for learning purpose.

I stuck in a thing, where I have to do show/hide of success and error message.

Here I have used jquery plugin in node js.

Below is the code :

```js
 const jsdom = require("jsdom");
            const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
            const { window } = new JSDOM();
            const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;
            global.document = document;
            global.jQuery   =  require('jquery')(window);
            global.$        = global.jQuery;
```

registration code :

```html
 doRegistration : (req , res) => {

        let email = req.body.email;
        let password = req.body.password;
        let name = req.body.name;
        let confirm_password = req.body.confirm_password;
        let encryptedString = cryptr.encrypt(req.body.password);


        if(email== '' || password == '' || name ==''  || confirm_password =='')
        {
        message = "Fields are empty";
          let  list2 = [];
         list2.name = '';
        list2.email = '';
        if(name!='')
        {
        list2.name =name;
        }
        if(email!='')
        {
        list2.email = email;
        }

        req.flash('error', message);

        setTimeout(function(){  $("#err").hide(); },3000); //not working 
        res.locals.message = req.flash();
        res.render('registration.ejs' ,{
        code : '204',
        title: "Registration",
        details :list2,

        });

        }


        }
```

setTimeout(function(){  $("#err").hide(); },3000);  this code has been added to hide the error message .Error message is not getting hide.

Is there anything wrong in my code.
Please suggest.
Thank you

Comment: you are writing client side event in server side script......

Comment: First I tried to do it in template side ,I am using ejs template . It did not work .

Comment: Can you show a snapshot of your view or template?

Comment: Ok give me some time , after putting code I share with u

Comment: I have used google cdn min file, I checked it now it is working. I think previously because of some caching issue it was not working.

Comment: Cool... Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bunch of code (in your first code block) which sets up a DOM and jQuery. You don't seem to ever populate the document with any data, but that's not your biggest problem.

In your registration code, you collect some data, inject it into `registration.ejs` and send the result to the client.

Three seconds later (by which time the HTTP request is **finished**, and the browser has whatever your sent), you call a jQuery function. This function operates on whatever `global.document` is.

`global.document` doesn't appear to have anything to do with `registration.ejs` and, even if it did, would change what was currently on the server without touching whatever is on the browser.

You **can't** write server-side JS that travels back in time and changes what the server sent to the browser three seconds earlier.

You **could** instead include a `<script>` element in the template file and run your jQuery *client-side*.

You **can't** write server-side code which initiates a connection to the browser (HTTP works with the browser initiating a communication with a request and the server providing a response) telling it to display a different document instead.

You **could** use WebSockets (or less elegant approaches like Comet or polling) so that when the page loads in the browser it initiates a connection to the server and then signal the browser to run some client-side code which hides the element. You still need to do the hiding with client-side code, this just allows you to determine *when* that happens on the server. There's no need for anything that complex if you just want to wait a short time.

Comment: Okay Let me try in template side again, I am using ejs here.